# How to select one column from multiple columns returning from a select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to select just one column from multiple columns in a select statement.

```
select 
    A, sum(B) paid
from
   T
where
    K LIKE '2015%'
group by A
having B >= 100
```

This query will return two columns but how to select just the first column from the select query? If I do something like this :

```
select A from (select 
    A, sum(B) paid
from
   T
where
    K LIKE '2015%'
group by A
having B >= 100 )
```

It is running into errors? Is there a way in mysql to select the only the first column ?

Comment: If you don't want the sum, why are you querying it?

Comment: how about doing what you are doing, but on the front end, just using one of them !

Comment: Sorry updated my question. There is a having clause with sum

Comment: do you want A or not ?

Comment: Do not use `like` for dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the two:

One

```
select A from (
  select A, sum(B) paid from T where K LIKE '2015%'
 group by A having sum(B) >= 100
) m
```

Two

```
select A from T where K like '2015%' group by A having sum(B)>=100
```

Comment: The first one will throwing this error `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Oh wait! what's the significance of `m` here ? :) this is working

Comment: `m` is the alias. Do not ignore it. The subquery `select A...` within brackets/paranthesis needs to have an alias. `m` is the alias.

Comment: I was missing this part. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your second query was correct just that you didn't add `sum` before the `b`

Try this

```
select A from (select 
    A, sum(B) paid
from
   T
where
    K LIKE '2015%'
group by A
having sum(B) >= 100 ) As temp
```

Comment: You have to append `m` like in @zedfoxus answer otherwise it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

You just want A you say.

```
select distinct A 
from T 
where k like '2015%' and B >= 100
```

btw, we don't know what datatype k is (ie: see Gordon's comment)

Mysql [year function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) for a date/datetime

so it would be `year(k)=2015`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that `K` is a date.  You should not use `like` for dates.  The best way to write the query is:

```
select A
from T
where K >= '2015-01-01' and K < '2016-01-01'
group by A
having sum(B) >= 100;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `T(K, A, B)`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for sharing this.